# IList vs IEnumerable : when they "executes" the LINQ query?

Tags: linq

I know that when I call some methods, it start to execute the whole LINQ query linked to that instance of the collection.

Example, every time I call `.Count()`. And I think also every time I call a `.ToList()`.

After getting a ToList(), I do a "copy" of that collection, than if I don't wrote any LINQ queries on the new instance of the collection, a Count() won't execute nothing. (right?)

And what about if I call a `.Union()` on 2 list? and on 2 Ienumerable? and with `.Except()` it is the same?

Tried with some Trace/Diagnostic, but I can't really understand when the LINQ query is executed.

Comment: Use reflector or other decompiler tools on such cases to be sure what's going on under the hood

Answer (score 2):

Union and Except are deferredly executed. Read remarks section in documentation for more info.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779

Also, in such situation when you are note sure what's happening under the hood, you can use Reflector or any other .NET decompiler. It's really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Answer on your question depends on two options:

- **Type of operation**: lazy (or deferred) and greedy. Lazy operations wouldn't be executed immediatly, and defered until code will start materializing data from your linq source. Greedy operations always execute immediatly.

  - Example of lazy operations: `.Union`, `.Except`, `.Where`, .`Select` and most of other linq operations
  - Greedy are: `.ToList`, `.Count` `.ToArray` and all operations that materialize data
- **Source of data** for your linq operations. While you're working with Linq to Memory all operations  (both lazy and greedy) will be executed immediately. Usualy Linq *to external sources of data* will execute lazy operations only during materialization.

Using this two rules you could anticipate how linq will behave:

1. `.Count` and `.ToList` will execute immediatly and materialize data
2. After `.ToList`, you'll get collection at memory, and all following operations will be executed immediatly (`.Count` will execute one again)
3. How will `.Union` and `.Except` behave as lazy or greedy depends on type of your data source. For memory they will be greedy, for SQL lazy.

Example for [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/). I have one `Enumerable` and lazy or deferred `.Where` and `.Select` operations on it before and after materializing using greedy `.Count` or `.ToList`:

```
void Main() 
{ 
    "get enumerable".Dump(); 
    var samplesEnumerable = GetSamples(); 

    "get count on enumerable #1".Dump(); 
    samplesEnumerable.Count().Dump(); 

    "get enumerable to list #1".Dump();  
    var list = samplesEnumerable.ToList();   

    "get count on list #1".Dump();   
    list.Count().Dump(); 

    "get count on list again #2".Dump(); 
    list.Count().Dump(); 

    "get where/select enumerable #1".Dump(); 
    samplesEnumerable 
        .Where(sample => { sample.Dump(); return sample.Contains("5"); }) 
        .Select(sample => { sample.Dump(); return sample; })
        .Dump(); 

    "get where/select list #1".Dump(); 
    list 
        .Where(sample => { sample.Dump(); return sample.Contains("5"); }) 
        .Select(sample => { sample.Dump(); return sample; })
        .Dump(); 
} 

string[] samples = new [] { "data1", "data2", "data3", "data4", "data5" }; 

IEnumerable<string> GetSamples() 
{ 
    foreach(var sample in samples)  
    { 
        sample.Dump(); 
        yield return sample; 
    } 
}
```

Sample output. Key points

1. On not materialized data, every `.Count` and `.List` are retrieving data again and again

   - `get count on enumerable #1`
   - `get where/select enumerable #1`
2. After materializing data, enumerable will be not retreived any more

   - `get enumerable to list #1`
   - `get count on list #1`
   - `get count on list again #2`
   - `get where/select list #1`

Output:

```
get enumerable
get count on enumerable #1
data1
data2
data3
data4
data5

5
get enumerable to list #1
data1
data2
data3
data4
data5
get count on list #1

5
get count on list again #2

5
get where/select enumerable #1
data1
data1
data2
data2
data3
data3
data4
data4
data5
data5
data5

data5 

get where/select list #1
data1
data2
data3
data4
data5
data5

data5
```

Comment: So every time I use a Greedy operation, it will execute all queries attachted to the Collection? That's I'd like to know...

Comment: I mean : I have a IEnumerable<T> and I do 4 queries on it. If I do a Count() I will execute this 4 queries. Than, if I do again Count() I will re-execute that 4 queries. But if I turn the IEnumerable into a List<T>, and if I do Count() 2 times, what's happens? The queries are executed again 2 times?

Comment: Yes, linq builds expression tree of lazy commands (on appropriate data source), and executes whole tree when reaching greedy command. Simples practical way to see how it's working, is to attach to logs of SQL server and add lazy commands one by one in debuger or linqpad. Or watch at Channel 9: (LINQ Beyond Queries)[http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/matthijs/LINQ-Beyond-Queries-by-Scott-Allen] and (LINQ Tips Tricks and Optimizations)[http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/matthijs/LINQ-Tips-Tricks-and-Optimizations-by-Scott-Allen]  by Scott Allen ;)

Comment: First, could you specify linq-2-_what?_ are you talking aboutL memory or not?

Comment: Yes, I use LINQ to manage my objects (in the memory) from SQL

Comment: I add extended sample that could be executed in linqpad, and you could extend it even more to find answers on your questions. Regarding your question: _But if I turn the IEnumerable into a List<T>, and if I do Count() 2 times, what's happens? The queries are executed again 2 times?_ — after materializing using `.ToList`, `.Count` will execute query two times but in memory only

Answer (score 0):

A Linq query is executed when it **has** a underlying collection but it **is** not a collection. You can materialze a query for example by using `ToList()` or `ToArray`.

Every deferred executed `Enumerable` extension tries first to cast the `IEnumerable<T>`to an `IList<T>`(f.e. if it needs an indexer) or to a `ICollection<T>`(f.e. if it needs a `Count`). If it can, it will use the "native" method which does not need to execute the query, otherwise it will enumerate the sequence.

Search for the tem *deferred* on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx) to see whether a method is executexd deferred or immediately. If you inspect the source code(f.e. via `ILSpy`), you can detect deferred executed methods by looking for the [`yield keyword`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx).

`Union` and `Except` are implemented using deferred execution. So you need a  `ToList`/`ToArray` if you want to persist that result.

Here's an example, the implementation of `Enumerable.Count`:

```
ICollection<TSource> collection = source as ICollection<TSource>;
if (collection != null)
{
    return collection.Count;
}
ICollection collection2 = source as ICollection;
if (collection2 != null)
{
    return collection2.Count;
}
int num = 0;
using (IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
{
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        num++;
    }
}
return num;
```

Comment: "A Linq query is executed when it's a query, not a collection" makes no sense.